# Referring URL to be same of the form URL in Pardot form handler

Tags: form, pardot

I have used the Pardot form handler in my page and used success URL as referring URL. But when the form is submitted the URL is changed to base address.

Example: if the form is at `x.com/y/z` on form submissions the URL is changed to `x.com`.

Shouldn't the URL remain the same and, if not, is there any way to make it?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? We're having the same issue!

Comment: @tobybot I couldnt find a direct way and used form handlers and used js to load to the referring url